# Copy node_modules into the docker container from outside

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

Can we copy the mode_modules from outside and paste it in the docker environment and use this for building the application (ng build --prod), so that we can avoid npm install step in docker file.

Ideally, I don't want to use the npm install step in docker file instead want to use the existing node_modeule packages created outside.

What I know docker images are created from base images which provide a working environment, is it possible to copy and paste from node_modules from outside to docker working environment.

Comment: Doing this is absolutely not recommended. You would want your dockerfile to be buildable instead of having a dependency on `node_modules`. Also sometimes these dependencies are OS specific and should never be copied at all

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing this, provided your host OS is a Linux distribution.  It's a more common approach using compiled languages, and was more common before there were multi-stage builds.  Is there a particular problem you're having doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should not be copying node_modules directory into the container. But if you absolutely need to do so then here is how to do it

Create a dockerfile and extend from your base image

```
FROM <your_base_nodejs_image>
```

Optionally, set a working directory inside the container

```
WORKDIR /app
```

Then assuming dockerfile is in the same directory as node_modules, you can do this

```
COPY ./node_modules ./node_modules
```

Alternatively, If you want to copy all of code in current directory into the container image, do this

```
COPY . .
```

Comment: I have no idea!

Comment: Agreed, installation of node_modules should happen as part of the image's build process, *not* copied from the CI server into the final image.

Comment: @guychouk in principle yes as it ensures that the image will not be faulty and have all the dependencies. In practice, no!!! because running yarn install inside docker takes forever. I benchmarked it it takes around 1822 seconds for nextjs, while running yarn install outside docker takes 82 seconds ;). In my ci I install the packages outside then just copy them over to the container. You can do tests if you want afteward to ensure container can start before pushing the image (I don't atm as ci is working fine)

Comment: @KristiJorgji I understand the pain of having to wait for Docker builds (specifically when talking about `node_modules` installations), but there are better ways to save the time and ensure correctness, e.g. building large dependencies ahead of time and using this pre-built image as the new base image. This is just one suggestion from the top of my head, perhaps there are even better ways to use Docker's image layering system, but using the CI server for building and copying over the node_modules is, IMHO, not the way to go.